# Android: unable to display Rewarded Video Ads even when event button is clicked

Tags: android, admob-rewardedvideoad

When I click the button to trigger the rewarded video ad, an Admob ad should show, However it doesn’t show up. Nothing happens. What are the possible mistakes that I might have made in my integration? Since it didn't work. I removed it so I don't have the codes now. Are there some samples or tips regarding the possibilities? Since I'm still a noob I would love to hear from you!

Comment: you are going to have to provide us with some code reference or a log of what happened in your application. There are many stages to integrate Admob ads in your application and a plethora of things could have gone wrong.

Comment: You have to load the AD before showing it.